# Перемешать три списка в одном и том же случайном порядке

Tags: python, list

Мне нужно перемешать три списка в одном и том же случайном порядке:

пример:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [56, 4, 7]
```

после перемешивания получилось вот так:

```
a = ['с', 'a', 'b'] 
b = [3, 1, 2] 
c = [7, 56, 4]
```

я пробовала сделать так (если что, то в x45_90 у меня три строки, то есть это `x45_90=[ [],[],[] ]`):

```
x45_90=[
['с', 'a', 'b'] ,
[3, 1, 2] ,
[7, 56, 4],
]

a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
a[:]=x45_90[0][:]
b[:]=x45_90[1][:]
c[:]=x45_90[2][:]
d = list(zip(a, b,c))
random.shuffle(d, random.random)
```

но выдает ошибку :

```
TypeError: Random.shuffle() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Как мне исправить ее?

Comment: вы, наверное, хотели сказать, что у вас в x45_90 три списка, а не три строки?

Comment: @strawdog да, все верно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По отредактированной версии исходных данных. Нужно просто распаковать `x45_90` при передаче аргументов в zip(): `zip(*x45_90)`.

```
import random

x45_90 = [
    ['с', 'a', 'b'],
    [3, 1, 2],
    [7, 56, 4],
]

x = list(zip(*x45_90))
random.shuffle(x)
a, b, c = (list(y) for y in zip(*x))
print(a, b, c, sep='\n')
```

```
['с', 'a', 'b']
[3, 1, 2]
[7, 56, 4]
```

Передавать второй аргумент в shuffle() не требуется и он удален с версии 3.11.: ["Changed in version 3.11: Removed the optional parameter random."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

Comment: У меня именно где  x45_90 не получается. На строке с shuffle выдается ошибка

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Есть два подхода: можно смешать списки вместе и можно перемешать индексы.

Смешивая вместе:

```
import random

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [56, 4, 7]

# x = [('a', 1, 56), ('b', 2, 4), ('c', 3, 7)] - список троек
x = list(zip(a, b, c))

random.shuffle(x)           # перемешиваем тройки

a[:], b[:], c[:] = zip(*x)  # разбираем тройки на отдельные списки

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Перемешивая индексы:

```
import random

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [56, 4, 7]

x = list(range(len(a)))  # x = [0, 1, 2] - список индексов

random.shuffle(x)        # перемешиваем индексы

# переставляем элементы списков в соответствии с индексами
a[:] = (a[i] for i in x)
b[:] = (b[i] for i in x)
c[:] = (c[i] for i in x)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```